# Docker compose named volume: find volume on host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume

I have a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

When I run this `docker-compose up -d` and then do `docker inspect -f '{{ (index .Mounts 0).Source }}' ef8be254a08b` for the running db container to get the Source which is specifying the volume location on the host, I always get "No such file or directory" if I `ls` the directory (`ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/test_db_data/_data: No such file or directory`).
How is that possible to get the real location for the volume?

Answer (score 7):

So I got the answer. The main point is that Docker on Mac is **still running inside a VM**. So the system paths are still relative to the VM, and not to your Mac. All the containers are stored within VM and located at `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2`

To go inside the VM use:

```
screen  ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

Then you can see contents of the Source folder given in `docker inspect {container_id}`:

```
ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/test_db_data/_data
```

Comment: Thank you for figuring this out.  Took me 4 hours today and was no closer to understanding why I couldn't get to it.